# How to get python data out of a string

Tags: python

I am setting up a lambda function to put data into a db.  I am using API gateway to control the endpoint.

The request I am making sends the data as a string:

```
      fetch(
        url,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ name: "hello", contact: "Tim", phone: "555" }),
        }
      );
```

My lambda function keeps erroring out because it doesn't know how to handle the string.

My function is:

```
import re
import psycopg2
import os
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    password = os.environ['DB_SECRET']
    host = os.environ['HOST']

    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password=password,
                                  host=host, port="5432",
                                  database="postgres")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgres_insert_query = "INSERT INTO clients (name, phone, contact) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}')".format(event.get('name'), event.get('phone'), event.get('contact'))
    cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query)
    print(cursor.rowcount)
    print(event['body'])
    connection.commit()                          
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
         'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
         },
    }
```

Now my print statement `print(event['body'])` returns `'{"name":"hello","contact":"Tim","phone":"555"}'` which is the exact data I need. However for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the data out of the string.

Comment: Why do you send it as a string rather than as an object? Also your function is vulnerable to sql-injections, don't use string.format for sql, instead use tools from the driver library you use, in this case psycopg2.sql.SQL

Comment: When I send the data as an object python receives is as `body: [object object]`

Comment: Ah, just checked and it is a horrible limitation of lambdas apparently. Alright, nevermind that, but you still need to correct your function

Comment: As of now it is possible to break your database even if I can think of a way to extract data out of it

Comment: I believe it is as simple as `name="name', 'random-phone', 'random-contact'); DROP stuff blindly; --"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

data = json.loads(event['body'])

print(data['name'])
```